# htaccess redirect if filename equals something

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to set a redirect (preferably with RewriteCond) so that if the requested file is index.php regardless of directory, it will be redirected to another site.

So visiting /index.php or/files/index.php or /stuff/index.php (etc.) will all redirect you to another domain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a general way to do it. This rule set should be placed in the .htaccess file in the root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  index\.php/?       [NC]
RewriteRule .*  http://otherdomain.com/      [R=301,L]
```

Redirects permanently any URL that holds `index.php` in any position, like

`http://mydomain.com/index.php` or

`http://mydomain.com/any/folder/quantity/index.php` or

`http://mydomain.com/any/folder/quantity/index.php/any/folder/quantity/`

To

`http://otherdomain.com/`

That's it. You don't explain much so nothing is passed to the other domain, just as you say in your question:

#### ...redirected to another site.

Answer (score 2):

These rules should do it (when placed inside `/.htaccess` file):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (?:^|/)index\.php$  http://otherdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```